# issue Rename files in sub directories

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to rename the below the name of files.
as you can see the some files have ".DSD".
So I want to remove these ".DSD"

I was just refering other ansering from here  such as

```
for /r %x in (*.DSD) do ren "%x" *.dad
```

But it does not work so
what am i supposed to do this ?

```
    before                                        after
DDS1_150223.cpj.DSD                         DDS1_150223.cpj                 
DDS1_150211.cpj.DSD                         DDS1_150211.cpj
72 ranndom value.xls                        72 ranndom value.xls
FREQUENCY_AGILE_MEM.mif.DSD                 FREQUENCY_AGILE_MEM.mif
....                                        ...
```

Comment: Are they all in the same directory or are there subdirectories that you also need to process?

Comment: @SomethingDark bunch of files are including in subdirectories also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command will work:

```
for /r %a in (*.DSD) do @move "%a" "%~pa%~na"
```

The command above make use of some optional syntax:

```
%~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
%~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
%~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
%~pI        - expands %I to a path only
%~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
%~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
%~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
%~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
%~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
%~zI        - expands %I to size of file
%~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
               environment variable and expands %I to the
               fully qualified name of the first one found.
               If the environment variable name is not
               defined or the file is not found by the
               search, then this modifier expands to the
               empty string
```

Comment: Thanks but when I came across some error message when I run that like D:\Downloads\Seeker_20160719>for /r %a in (*.DSD) do @move "%a" "%~pa%~na"
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~pa%~na"

For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
bat.bat was unexpected at this time.

Comment: You ran this command in a command prompt window or in a batch file?

Comment: then you should use: for /r %%a in (*.DSD) do @move "%%a" "%%~pa%%~na"